# How to fix an error of "invalid connection" in R

Tags: r, geospatial, modeling, maxent

I have been using R code to predict the future distribution of small mammal species based on records of their occurrence in the Atlantic Forest and predictions of environmental variables. I used this code just fine throughout last year:

```
maxent <- BIOMOD_Modeling(bm.format=PA_data,    
                          models=c("MAXENT"), 
                          bm.options = max_params, 
                          nb.rep=50,    
                          prevalence = 0.5,
                          data.split.perc=70,
                          var.import=0,
                          metric.eval=c("TSS","ROC"),
                          save.output=TRUE,
                          scale.models=TRUE,
                          do.full.models=FALSE,
                          modeling.id=paste(sp))
```

But now it gives the following error after starting to run Maxent through the BIOMOD_Modeling function:

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Build Single Models -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=


Checking Models arguments...

     MAXENT default prevalence option was updated to fit with modeling prevalence (i.e 0.5 )
Creating suitable Workdir...

            ! Weights where automatically defined for Caluromys.philander_PA1 to rise a 0.5 prevalence !


-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Caluromys.philander Modeling Summary -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

 8  environmental variables ( bio_12 bio_13 bio_18 bio_19 bio_2 bio_4 bio_8 bio_9 )
Number of evaluation repetitions : 50
Models selected : MAXENT 

Total number of model runs: 50 

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=


-=-=-=- Run :  Caluromys.philander_PA1 


-=-=-=--=-=-=- Caluromys.philander_PA1_RUN1 
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

I already tried updating R and all of my R packages, but nothing worked, and the rest of the code seems fine.
What could be the problem?